# Show that product of integer polynomial values for arguments being complex roots of unity is integer.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, integers, roots-of-unity

$P(x)$ is polynomial with integer coefficients and $w$ is complex (primitive) root of unity  of a degree $n$. Show that $P(1)*P(w)*P(w^2)*...*P(w^{n-1})$ is integer number for every natural number $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w_k=w^k$. Then $Q(w_0, w_1, \dots,w_{n-1})=P(w_0) \cdot P(w_1) \cdot P(w_2) \cdots P(w_{n-1})$ is a polynomial [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) in $w_0, w_1, \dots,w_{n-1}$. Therefore $Q$ can be expressed as a polynomial in the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in $w_k$ with integer coefficients. But, since $w$ is a *primitive* $n^{th}$ root of unity,  $w_k=w^k \;|\; k=0 \dots n-1$ are the $n$ roots of $x^n - 1=0$ which is a monic polynomial with integer coefficients, so by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) all the elementary symmetric polynomials in $w_k$ are integers (in fact, all of them $0$ except the full product which is $1$), thus $Q$ is an integer as well.